# Can I save the exact state of the clipboard in Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, clipboard

I want to save the *exact* state of the clipboard for future reference. Is there a way I can do this?

For example, if I copied and pasted something from a rich textbox and pasted it into [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29), all I would get was the raw text, not any other metadata such as bold, font, etc.

If I paste it into [WordPad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPad), I get some metadata, but not necessarily all of it. The same with copying cells from [Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel), or a selection of an image from an image editor. The only application I know of that can guarantee acceptance of the entire clipboard is the one from which I just copied.

I want to copy something that has unique metadata from one program, save the clipboard state, and be able to reboot the computer and recover the same data. I can then paste it into the same application.

Is there a way to save the clipboard state? Can I install a replacement clipboard for Windows that has this ability? Is there some program that accepts the raw binary data from the clipboard?

Comment: Yes its possible but the program which copies the clipboard must support doing so.

Comment: could this be what you need? http://www.sttmedia.com/clipboardsaver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple clipboard viewer that has the ability to save/load the complete state of the clipboard: http://www.freeclipboardviewer.com/

The Windows clipboard has the ability to store multiple alternative formats for data, e.g. if you copy from a web browser, you might get plain text, rich text and HTML formats stored. Many applications will also store their "native" representation of the data.

Note that for some applications (e.g. Microsoft Excel) the "native" format is actually just a reference to the source, so saving, rebooting and loading won't work quite as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Clipboard is meant to be a transient store of data. You will need to use other applications such as

- [Ditto](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ditto-cp/)
- [M8 Free Multi Clipboard](http://m8software.com/clipboards/freeclip/freeclip.htm)
- [ArsClip](http://www.joejoesoft.com/cms/showpage.php?cid=97)
- [Yankee Clipper](http://www.intelexual.com/products/YC3/)